# Node JS Error: spawn node-7z-forall/binaries/linux/7za ENOENT

Tags: node.js, linux, npm

I am using the module `node-7z-forall` and tried to extract a file. and ending with below error

```
{ Error: spawn <project-path>/node_modules/node-7z-forall/binaries/linux/7za ENOENT
     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
   errno: 'ENOENT',
   code: 'ENOENT',
   syscall:
    'spawn <project-path>/node_modules/node-7z-forall/binaries/linux/7za',
   path:
    '<project-path>/node_modules/node-7z-forall/binaries/linux/7za',
   spawnargs:
    [ 'x',
      '/tmp/QMTH1648468809779.zip',
      '-o/tmp/QMTH1648468809779',
      '-pkarnatakaBank',
      '-ssc',
      '-y',
      '-bb2' ] }
```

please help me on this

Answer (score 0):

Hi I found the solution for my problem:
Some dependencies were not installed properly. Removed the existing module and reinstalled again. and it worked for me.